# html tabs kick back to home page instead of showing new data

Tags: html

I'm trying to implement a html tabbed interface. For some reason clicking on a tab will kick me back to the homepage instead of showing a new list of data. Do I need to add a url route to the `<a href>` ?

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#overview" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#documents" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Documents</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#punchlist" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">List</a></li>
    </ul>
 <div id="mainBody">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="overview">
            <div role="tabpanel">
               DATA 1
            </div>
        </div>
       <div class="tab-pane" id="documents">
            <div role="tabpanel">
               DATA 2
            </div>
        </div>
       <div class="tab-pane" id="punchlist">
            <div role="tabpanel">
               DATA 3
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I noticed your IDs don't have closing quotation marks. I would suggest fixing that first, and seeing if things work.

Comment: @Patrick, silly mistake I made while simplifying the code for the question. I had the closing quotation marks in my actual code

Comment: Show your Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you are just trying to show the contents of the tab then I would change your href="#something" to href="javascript: return false;" or put the code in your event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Tested this over on Bootply

http://www.bootply.com/DqUJfu6r4z

You simply need to close the quotations on your IDs:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#overview" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#documents" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Documents</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#punchlist" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">List</a></li>
    </ul>
 <div id="mainBody">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="overview">
            <div role="tabpanel">
               DATA 1
            </div>
        </div>
       <div class="tab-pane" id="documents">
            <div role="tabpanel">
               DATA 2
            </div>
        </div>
       <div class="tab-pane" id="punchlist">
            <div role="tabpanel">
               DATA 3
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I've reviewed my code and there is no difference from what's here, however it still kicks me back to the main page. When clicking a tab it is actively searching for a localhost:/#punchlist page.

Comment: Then I would posit that the javascript is not being referenced properly. Are you using Bootstrap? If you're running off localhost, what server are you using? be sure that all the files have the correct path.